# Webapp2_extras.auth with backend 'datastore' not working properly

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

Setting the session backend to datastore will not work properly because every call to auth.get_user_by_session() causes a put() to the datastore of the session entity even if you didn't modify the session values.

That's caused because a call to auth.get_user_by_session() makes a call to auth.get_session_data(pop=True). Pop=True will indeed pop the _user from the session dict object (SessionDict from the webapp2_extras.sessions) which causes the session to get the attribute **modified** to True.

Therefore when the handler completes it's tasks a call to save_session in the handler dispatch method will check if the session was modified and if True (which always is TRUE!!!) will do the put to the datastore.

So, for every request the session is put to the datastore because obviously you're calling auth.get_user_by_session() on each request.

I don't know how to handle this but I have already open a issue in the google code project page (which seems abandoned):
https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=100&sort=-id

Can anyone help me understand what's happening here? and how can I solve this?

Comment: The title of your question is a little off ... I think webapp2_extras.sessions is behaving as expected, and the backend being used isn't pertinent. The problem you have is with webapp2_extras.auth (I've never used it, but it looks wrong/weird to me too, for what that's worth).

Comment: That's completely true.. and I changed the tittle. The problem is with the auth module. Why get_session_data pops the user from the session??

Answer (score 1):

So, if we inspect the following code from `webapp2_extras.auth` you the get the following:

```
def get_user_by_session(self, save_session=True):
        """Returns a user based on the current session.

        :param save_session:
            If True, saves the user in the session if authentication succeeds.
        :returns:
            A user dict or None.
        """
        if self._user is None:
            data = self.get_session_data(pop=True)
            if not data:
                self._user = _anon
            else:
                self._user = self.get_user_by_token(
                    user_id=data['user_id'], token=data['token'],
                    token_ts=data['token_ts'], cache=data,
                    cache_ts=data['cache_ts'], remember=data['remember'],
                    save_session=save_session)
        return self._user_or_none()
```

After that lets inspect the `get_session_data()`

```
def get_session_data(self, pop=False):
        """Returns the session data as a dictionary.

        :param pop:
            If True, removes the session.
        :returns:
            A deserialized session, or None.
        """
        func = self.session.pop if pop else self.session.get
        rv = func('_user', None)
        if rv is not None:
            data = self.store.deserialize_session(rv)
            if data:
                return data
            elif not pop:
                self.session.pop('_user', None)

        return None
```

I do not see where why it pops in case you have a user in the session? it points to the user_or_none which unsets the session if the user is None.

Amazing blog post on built in authorization in webapp2:

http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: I don't see this as a correct answer. Setting pop to True will call self.session.pop('_user', None) which will set the session attribute modified to True (see SessionDict class) and therefore will always put() to the datastore even if you don't modify the session.

Comment: Yes, but it never gets called if you actually have a user in the session.

Comment: Yes but notice that self._user is used to cach the user for every request. So the first time for every request self_user is always None. See https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/auth.html#Auth

Comment: The key thing here is Why pop the user from the session instead of just get it? see that in get_user_by_session pop=True is hard coded. You can't change it. I think it's a bug.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that the (pop=True) in `get_user_by_session` seems like a bug. Might be worth sending in a patch with a fix and attaching it to the issue you opened against the project?

Comment: don't know how to do this... I was playing around more with the auth module and I think it has more bugs.

Comment: @janscas Jancas, could you point us to the bugs you found? I am using the auth module extensively, so I'm a bit worried.

Comment: If you just use it with secure_cookie backend it's ok, because the "cost" of rewrite the cookie is nothing important.
The problem comes when you use the datastore backend. Here I post the issue: https://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=100

Comment: webapp2 seems to be death. Nobody is improving it or answering the issues.